# Magento 2 - Overwrite module-swatches view.xml

Tags: magento2, theme

How do you overwrite the `view.xml` in `\vendor\magento\module-swatches\etc\view.xml` in your own template?

I want to overwrite the sizes for **swatch_image** and **swatch_image_base**. I tried putting the code in `\...\mytheme\etc\view.xml` and in `\...\mytheme\Magento_Swatches\etc\view.xml` but it does not work.

The other theme stuff works, so the theme is correctly set up.

Changing the values directly in the original `view.xml` works as well.

Edit: Full Code in `\app\design\frontend\\{Vendor}\\{theme}\etc\view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
                <width>50</width>
                <height>50</height>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
                <width>50</width>
                <height>50</height>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply changes under `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/etc/view.xml` file.

For changes value of swatches you have to add your  tag inside `view.xml` files

```
<media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
            <width>30</width>
            <height>20</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
            <width>30</width>
            <height>20</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
```

You can keep your specific field inside images tag.

Now applying changes you have to clear cache and var folder.

Comment: In the backend all caches are disabled. Do I only need to clear /var/cache/?

Comment: First try it without if not working then delete and check.

Comment: It is not working unfortunately. I have the code in /theme/etc/view.xml and deleted all contents in /var/cache

Comment: Add your full code so i will check.

Comment: Can you specify Magento 2 version ?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.1.0

Comment: You can get more information from : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2978. something wrong with magento version.

Comment: change values in /vendor/magento/module-swatch/etc/module.xml this file. Is working or not ? it is just for testing purpose.

Comment: You mean the view.xml? Changing the values there works.

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020463/how-can-we-change-size-of-an-attribute-swatch-image-in-magento2

Comment: Well the code from the accepted answer is the same I already have in my view.xml, isn't it?
And in the second answer it is suggested to put it directly in the vendor directory, which already works when I put it there in the view.xml.
The thing is I want to change the size in my theme, not in the vendor path.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like M 2.1.x has some issues with this.
Not only is needed to add your own `<media>` tag in `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/etc/view.xml` as already mentioned:

```
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
    <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
        <width>30</width>
        <height>20</height>
    </image>
    <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
        <width>110</width>
        <height>90</height>
    </image>
    <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
        <width>30</width>
        <height>20</height>
    </image>
    <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
        <width>110</width>
        <height>90</height>
    </image>
</images>
```

but, as is written in this issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6382, you'll need to add a DI to override for `Magento\Framework\View\Config::getViewConfig()` in your module. Make you own class `\Vendor\Theme\Framework\View\Config` and copy the `getViewConfig()` method from the original class.

You should replace line 74 from

```
$config = $this->viewConfigFactory->create($viewConfigParams);
```

to

```
$config = $this->viewConfigFactory->create();
```

I've tried myself and worked after cleaning the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a copy of it into **app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/Magento_Swatches/etc/view.xml**