# How to override or extend etc/view.xml file in custom module in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, module, xml, gallery, image-resize

I would like to **override** or **extend** some of gallery setting(view.xml) and catalog image size changes with my custom module.

I have tried to override in `app/code/<vendor>/<module>/etc/view.xml`, but not working.

How can I override `etc/view.xml` in custom module ?

Comment: try with app/code/<vendor>/<module>/etc/frontend/view.xml

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4663

Answer (score 0):

The doc will show you how to override elements at a class, block, layout or template level. For the product gallery in particular and if you need your changes to be in a module, there are a few options:

- Theme: override the theme you need to customise from a custom child theme, where you can do whatever you want with a custom view.xml file definition.
- Template: override vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml in your custom module.
- Class: override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Gallery block class in your custom module.

If you want to alter the product images before they are displayed, you can retrieve the gallery images using $galleryImages = $product->getMediaGalleryImages() on a product instance.

If you want to (programmatically) go deeper than overriding the product gallery block class, you will have to consider using Magento 2 plugins. They allow you to define "before", "after", and "around" hooks that can help you alter the core logic.

Optionally or alternatively, your custom module can implement CSS and JS files that alter the gallery aspect or behaviour on a UI level, after page load.

Answer (score -1):

You must do the override in `app/design` directory and not in `app/code`

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/etc/view.xml
```

Comment: he clearly mentioned that he want to use it in custom module not a theme brother. so please remove your answer.

Comment: i see it not possible to do it from app/code,  never seen something like that or read it.

Comment: i know that it's not possible to do so we can close this question if want answer as you suggest then https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144518/magento-2-overwrite-module-swatches-view-xml